# Testing CORS compatibility for IE8 using developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cors, developer-tools

I've set up a central WebApi site that will provide general CRUD capability for various sites across our domain. I've configured the whole shebang to utilize CORS with the standard jquery ajax `httprequest` or, in the case of older IE versions, `XDomainRequest`. So far, everything checks out, it works splendidly. My problem is that I can't seem to find a machine with IE8 in order to complete user agent testing. The site works wonderfully when I go into the developer tools on IE 11 and set it to emulate IE8 but I'm not ready to pop the champagne cork just yet.

My question is: will the developer tools' IE8 mode fully emulate that browser's behavior, down to the way it handles cross domain requests or do I need to either find a user with IE8 and have them test it or spin up a VM with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a virtual machine with IE8 from Microsoft's modern.ie site at http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/ and test your site with that.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. That's pretty useful. I'm still curious to know if switching versions in dev tools only affects the way the page is rendered.

Comment: I switched to testing with the IE8 VM because I found the developer tools setting for IE8 did not always work the same as a true IE8, but I don't remember exactly what the issue was. :(

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. I took out the piece of javascript that I'd put in there to make IE9 and lower work corretcly with CORS and they still went through instead of erroring out, which was the expected behavior.